# Shabbos clothing during Sheva Brachos

Tags: clothing, sheva-brachos

Are there any sources or any reasons why a chosson and kallah should wear Shabbos clothing during all seven days of Sheva Brachos? I've seen it commonly done in some circles. Also, since the Halacha is that the chosson can't do malacha during these days, apparently there is some special significance to these days besides making Sheva brachos.

Comment: Don't confuse the prohibition of melacha with holiday status.the prohibition is just so he spend time with his wife, not with other pursuits.

Answer (score 1):

[Nitei Gavriel Nusuin2 - 55:14:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=32&hilite=) says that the Chasan and Kallah should wear Bigdei Shabbos Vyom Tov the entire week of the Sheva Brachos. He brings it in the name of the [Pirkei D'Rav Eliezer 16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22744&st=&pgnum=70), Itur Birchas Chasanim 63b, Avudraham, and Menoras Hamoar.

Comment: Two minor corrections first of all, the PDE says nothing about the bride; it only mentions the groom. Second of all, it is not clear that it is saying that the hattan _should_ wear nice clothes, it might just mean that he often does. It says 
מַה הַמֶּלֶך לוֹבֵשׁ בִּגְדֵי כָבוֹד, כָּךְ הֶחָתָן לוֹבֵשׁ בִּגְדֵי כָבוֹד כָּל שִׁבְעַת יְמֵי הַמִּשְׁתֶּה but is also says 
מָה הַמֶּלֶךְ פָּנָיו מְאִירוֹת כְּאוֹר הַחַמָּה, כָּךְ הֶחָתָן פָּנָיו מְאִירוֹת כְּאוֹר הַחַמָּה. The latter is clearly a mere description; not a ruling of what one must do, or even a recommendation.

Comment: Importantly, the Ittur demarcates this section with the word "haggadah" that is, this is not a halakhic matter, but an aggadic one.

Comment: Importantly the Abudirham isnt endorsing the PDE's view that the hattan wears nice clothes; in context, he is just bringing it to show that the hattan is like a king, to explain the recitation of a particular Psalm (apparently Psalm 58) which mentions a king.